# Create a function that takes a string as an argument and returns a coded (h4ck3r 5p34k) version of the string

Tags: javascript

```
 function hackerSpeak(str){
    for (var i=0; i <str.length;i++)
      {
    if (str[i]="a")
       {str[i].replace("a",4)}
    else if (str[i]="e")
        {str[i].replace("e",3)}
    else if (str[i]="i") 

     {str[i].replace("i",1)}
    else if (str[i]="o")
          {str[i].replace("o",0)}
    else if (str[i]="s")
          {str[i].replace("s",5)}
    else {}
        }
    return str
  }

  document.write (hackerSpeak("become a coder"))
```

The output is the same as input, and I can't find the problem using console.  In order to work properly, the function should replace all 'a's with 4, 'e's with 3, 'i's with 1, 'o's with 0, and 's's with 5.

Comment: `String.replace()` doesn't change the original string. Assign the results of the replace to another variable, and return it.

Comment: `=` is assignment - not comparison.  For comparison use `==` or `===`.

Comment: Try this

```
function hackerSpeak (string) {

Comment: @PM77-1 Strings are array-like in javascript, iterating over them like this is valid.

Comment: @Klaycon - You are right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`String#replace` does not work *in situ* (it does not mutate the original string), but returns a new one.

I would suggest you to keep using replace function but also try some regex :)

```js
const dictionary = {
   a: 4,
   e: 3,
   i: 1,
   o: 0,
   s: 5,
};

function hackerSpeak(str) {
  return str.replace(/[aeios]/gi, (m) => dictionary[m]); 
  // it will return new, modified string
}

document.write(hackerSpeak("become a coder"))
```

Comment: Is `document.write` necessary? Why not using `console.log`?

Comment: @customcommander Yeah, console.log is also fine, just wanted to be consistent with the asker

Comment: @customcommander `document.write` fits the usage in the original question, it is good to be consistent and include it in the answer.

Comment: `[aeios]` is redundant and error prone - since there's already a dictionary. Also `A` (uppercase) will never become `4`, such a pity. **I'd suggest** rather: https://jsfiddle.net/zv0wq8pu/

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan All this effort to avoid repeating exactly five characters doesn't seem like a huge improvement to  me

Comment: @customcommander effort? It's just using what we already have. A dict. And JS's  Object.keys. One day you can modify say 15 characters - in one place. And rest assured you've done it right.

Comment: I would even go a step further to get rid of the complicated or hardcoded Regex. `.replace(/\w/gi, (m) => m in dictionary ? dictionary[m] : m);` @RokoC.Buljan

Comment: @kinduser that's also interesting, but I like more letting RegExp inernals handle the iteration for me, without the need to apply a Ternary operator check with `in` for every single character in a string...

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan You're assuming that characters that need to be replaced can be directly transposed into a regular expression. Say you need to replace these three characters `a`, `-` and `e`, then programmatically creating a regular expression as you do will return `new RegExp('[a-e]')` which will match characters `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` and `e` (and won't match `-` at all). In a generated regular expression, you generally need to double escape special characters.

Comment: @customcommander your comment is almost on point. If special characters are needed, it can be done right in the lib key propertyName i.e: `'\-': '+'`, so, **in one place** much simpler and elegant. The caveat persists in both scenarios anyways - and is much simpler to accommodate it by using my suggestion. Otherwise you'd end up doing `'-' : '+'` in one place and `[a\-e]` in another.  Think again ;)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I shall respectfully disagree with you on this. Anyway if it comes to that point I would simply split the string and lookup the map for each character ;)

Comment: @customcommander talking about performance, on a simple character-by-character replacer (simple string manipulation O(n)), - that's what I'd do too.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const hackerSpeak = (statement) => {
    const leet = {'a': 4, 'b': 3, 'i': 1, 'o': 0, 's': 5}
    const speak = letter => leet.hasOwnProperty(letter) ? leet[letter] : letter

    return statement.split('').map(speak).join('')
}

console.log(hackerSpeak("i become a super coder"));
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all:
a single "=" is no comparison operator in JavaScript.
"=" is vor value assignment. To compare two values, use "==" or "===".

for string comparison consider to use ".equals(...)"

Comment: Absolutely no need to use `equals` in JS.